# Why does my python script using locks to pause on asynchronous keyboard input gets stuck only on long pauses

Tags: python, concurrency, locking

I have a python program that has a run loop animating the screen with tinter. I am trying to implement a feature where if a key is pressed the animation pauses until the key is released.

I am using pynput keyboard to asynchronously listen for key commands and threading locks to try and create this behavior.

My first attempt is not working well.

If you briefly press a key everything works fine. However if you hold that key down for a bit the program gets permanently stuck with no error.

```
from pynput import keyboard
import threading
import time

pauseLock = threading.Lock()
def on_press(key):
    try:
        pauseLock.acquire()
        print("Paused")
    except AttributeError:
        pass

def on_release(key):
    pauseLock.release()
    print("Unpaused")
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        return False

# Collect events until released
listener = keyboard.Listener(
    on_press=on_press,
    on_release=on_release)
listener.start()

while True:
    time.sleep(0.01) # in seconds
    pauseLock.acquire()
    print("Hello")
    pauseLock.release()
```

I guess I don't understand why this is happening and how to get around it. It must be something specific to Pythons implementation of threads and locks because I feel like this would work well in other languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem stems from the fact that `pynput` repeatedly calls the key press event handler for as long as a key is being held, so with your code it would first successfully acquire a lock when you initially press a key but when you hold the key the subsequent attempts to acquire a lock would block indefinitely even after you release the key because the lock is only released once by the release event handler but many blocking acquire attempts remain with nothing further to release them.

You should therefore keep track of which keys are currently pressed on your own with a set, and only release the lock when the set is empty:

```
pressed = set()

def on_press(key):
    if not pressed:
        try:
            pauseLock.acquire()
            print("Paused")
        except AttributeError:
            pass
    pressed.add(key)

def on_release(key):
    pressed.remove(key)
    if not pressed:
        pauseLock.release()
        print("Unpaused")
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        return False
```